# How to create an WSO2 Store application with a callback URL using the Rest API in version 2.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a new application in the WSO2 APIM Store  `v2.2.0u4` via its REST API using the following payload:

```
{
  "throttlingTier": "Unlimited",
  "description": "Test application",
  "name": "testapp1",
  "callbackUrl": "http://my.server.com/callback"
}
```

When I open the newly created application in the Store the callback URL is empty and the Grant type "Code" and "Implicit" are not checked. Inside the database (table `am_application`) the callback URL has the correct value.

Accordingly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136310/wso2am-1-10-0-how-to-set-default-oauth2-grant-types) when the callback URL is set these grant options are checked by default.

Is this a bug in this version? I did the same thing in version `1.10.0` and it worked as expected.